# How to use Firebase push notification with Ionic application?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

i want to use Firebase push notification with ionic and Coradova plugin for push notification .  after long search i cannot use it with FireBase SDK .
is there any type of API or setting to set that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this plugin and see. It works.

https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm